# Updating table parse error

Tags: php, mysql

Overview:
i am crating a dummy website for learning purposes therefore its functionalists are basic and security in not on the agenda atm.

Problem:
When i login into a system and click edit account button i get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\eshop\userEditAccount.php on line 104

userEditAccount.php file:

```
<?php


session_start();



    require_once('userEditAccount.php');
    include('connect_mysql.php');


    if(isset($_POST['Editsubmited'])){

    $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    $Newusername = $_POST['username'];
    $Newpassword = $_POST['password'];
    $Newfirstname = $_POST['first_name'];
    $Newlastname = $_POST['last_name'];
    $Newemail = $_POST['email'];



    $sql = "UPDATE users SET username='$Newusername', password='$Newpassword',
    first_name='$Newfirstname', last_name='$Newlastname WHERE user_id='$userid'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql)  or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error()); 

    if(!$result){
        exit("Error Ocured whilsd updating $ud_id record");
    }
    echo "Record $ud_id has been sucesfully updated";


mysql_close($con);

?>


<html>
<head>

<title>Edit Account</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <header><h1>E-Shop</h1></header>


        <article>
        <h1>Welcome</h1>

            <h1>Edit Account</h1>

        <div id="login">

                <ul id="login">

                <form method="post" name="editAccount" action="userEditAccount.php"  >
                    <fieldset>  
                        <legend>Fill in the form</legend>

                        <label>Select Username : <input type="text" name="username" /></label>
                        <label>Password : <input type="password" name="password" /></label>
                        <label>Enter First Name : <input type="text" name="first_name" /></label>
                        <label>Enter Last Name : <input type="text" name="last_name" /></label>
                        <label>Enter E-mail Address: <input type="text" name="email" /></label>
                    </fieldset>
                        <br />

                        <input name="Editsubmited" type="submit" submit="submit" value="Edit Account" class="button">

                </form>

                <?

                    echo $newrecord;
                ?>


                </div>
            <form action="userhome.php" method="post">
            <div id="login">
                <ul id="login">
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" value="back" onclick="index.php" class="button">   
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>      



        </article>
<aside>
</aside>

<div id="footer">This is my site i Made coppyrights 2013 Tomazi</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Looking at the code everything looks to be right and the error makes no sense unexpected end of file.........

when i use the php code in a separate  file and link this file with the html file then i get the same error in the file where php is therefore i guess its something to do with php....

Any suggestions Overflowers:....?

Comment: omg people i am learning i am trying to establish the basic functionalities before enhancing the code this site will never go on line. I am very aware of the security issues and the SQL injection issues.

Comment: and its hard to learn if I post a question to get help and learn something and all this "clever wonnabe people" look for any reason to dislike something. Like everybody makes things perfect from the start!!!!

Comment: Well i do not agree @MikeB i am a C++ programmer and from experiences before the code is fully enhanced and genuine version is released......The code goes through many changes over the time of development, the biggest mistake in my opinion is to try develop PERFECT software from first go this is when projects fails, run out of money and are never accomplished, tHATS WHY PROGRAMERS DO PROTOTYPES AND BETA VERSIONS

Comment: HOPEFULLY @MikeB THID WOULD MAKE YOU HAPPY $newPassword = stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not close your if:

```
 if(isset($_POST['Editsubmited'])){
```

To prevent this error in the future make sure to properly indent your code, this makes it much easier to find braces that belong together and see missing braces.

Comment: ok thx that worked *faceslap* but now when i submit the query no errors pop up but no changes occurred in database

Answer (score 0):

the below mentioned if statement is not closed:

```
if(isset($_POST['Editsubmited'])){
```

close this function after the `echo $newrecord;` statement

Comment: ok thx that worked *faceslap* but now when i submit the query no errors pop up but no changes occurred in database

Comment: try these lines in the update section ... if (!mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_con)){} $result=mysql_query($query, $db_con);
 $rowcount=@mysql_num_rows($result);

 if ( $rowcount > 0 ) -> then ur update was successful